# Cart count not updating in navigation bar while popViewController in swift

Tags: swift, count, uinavigationbar, popviewcontroller

**I have created custom navigation bar with cart and its count like below code:** like this if i call `setUpNavigationBar()` in all viewcontrollers i am getting navigationbar with cart and count

```
func setUpNavigationBar(){

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = CommonColor.navigationColor
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = CommonColor.navigationColor
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.masksToBounds = false

let cartBtn: BadgeButton = BadgeButton(type: .custom)
cartBtn.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon55"), for: .normal)
cartBtn.addAction(for: .touchUpInside) {
print("in cart")
let signupVC = (StoryBoard.driver).instantiateViewController(identifier: "ShoppingCartVC") as! ShoppingCartVC
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(signupVC, animated: true)
}
cartBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
let cartQty = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "cartCount")
cartBtn.badgeText = cartQty as? String
let btnCart = UIBarButtonItem(customView: cartBtn)

self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(btnCart, animated: true)

}

func setBadgeCountForCart(with : String?){
let badge = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.map({$0.customView}).filter({$0 is BadgeButton}).first as? BadgeButton
badge?.badgeText = with
}
```

but in  `ShoppingCartVC` i don't want navigation bar so, i didn't call `setUpNavigationBar` in ShoppingCartVC viewdidload

so if remove product from cart and i click **back** button in `ShoppingCartVC` then the cartConut is not updating in poped viewcontroller

**after remove product i have updated cartCount like below:**

```
class ShoppingCartVC: UIViewController {

 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    self.serviceCall()
}
func serviceCall(){
 self.cartDB = ShoppingCartDetaModel(dictionary: responseData.dict as NSDictionary? ?? NSDictionary())
            
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.cartDB?.result?.cart?.total_item, forKey: "cartCount")
            self.setUpNavigationBar()

}

@IBAction func back(_ sender: UIButton){
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
    self.serviceCall()
    UserDefaults.standard.set(self.cartDB?.result?.cart?.total_item, forKey: "cartCount")
    self.setUpNavigationBar()
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

}
```

where should i change, please do help

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the `BadgeButton` its `text` property with the updated quantity after you navigated back. You can use different methods for achieving that. The easiest and less clean one is to call `self.setUpNavigationBar()` in the `viewWillAppear` method. A cleaner way is to use the `NotificationCenter` class or a `Publisher` and post an update every time the quantity changes.

ViewWillAppear: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear

NotificationCenter: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter

Publisher: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher

Comment: you know, in ShoppingCartVC  `viewWillAppear` i am  hiding the navBar.. i know thats the problem.. but i don't want navigationbar in   `ShoppingCartVC ` now how to update cartCOunt when i pop.. pls help

Comment: i have edited my post with `viewWillAppear` take a look and please do help